# Django & POST from Ajax

Tags: ajax, django, post

I've been trying to get a POST to my Django views with the final goal to send a 'selected' input (from a clicked #id) and have Django send a response which I can dynamicly show. Using GET I'm able to recieve a response but the POST is giving me problems (I could go for GET but at this time I just want to understand why I'm messing up POST...;))

I have used several guides by now but most are about forms and, to be honest, I have trouble following the documentation (I have little to no background in programming).

Could someone point me in the right direction?

My HTML ('numberinput' is a placeholder for now):

```
<script>
    $("#test").on(click(function () {
        numberinput = 8;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '{% url "rungenerator" %}',
            data: {'numberinput': numberinput},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (inputtype) {
                alert(inputtype)

            }

        })
    }))

</script>

<div>
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button type="submit" id="test">Buzzzz Ping</button>

    </form>
</div>
```

Views:

```
def rungenerator(request):
    inputtype = "Please make a selection"

    if request.method == 'POST':
        inputtype = request.POST['numberinput',None]
    return JsonResponse(inputtype)
```

URLS:

```
url(r'^ajax/rungenerator/$', views.rungenerator, name='rungenerator'),
```

Comment: what is the error, can you check what is the response? Also check this [Ajax](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html) example.

Comment: The browser console gives me a "POST http://IP#/generator/ 405 (Method Not Allowed)" (I've visited the link before and will do again, thanks)

Comment: What happens when you just use a relative url instead of a template tag? Instead of {% url "rungenerator" %} just do '/ajax/rungenerator/' as the url; 405 can be deceptive and is often caused by a bad URL

Comment: This also prompts a 405. I was guessing the URLS would not contain my problem as GET does work.

Answer (score 0):

**@csrf_exempt** Will allow you to bypass the token validation. Please check if your **Ajax** call is making the cross-origin error. if that the case you should either use **cors-headers** on your django app. btw using **require_http_methods** will force the function to check the HTTP method so you can be 100% sure all data that you will get will be **POST**

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods
from django.http import HttpResponse

@csrf_exempt
@require_http_methods(["POST"])
def rungenerator(request):
    inputtype = request.POST.get('numberinput', None)
    payload = {"response":str(inputtype)} if inputtype is not None else {"response":"please type something"}
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(payload, indent=2),
                            content_type='application/json',
                            status=200)
```

Comment: sadly still a 405 response.

Comment: you checked your header response.... what it says?  405 Method Not Allowed
it means that you are lets say sending GET and you can only send POST in my code example you are using POST so you need to send POST values. I tested the code and works. please check your header response.

Comment: It starts off with a 403 from rungenerator/ (REQUEST Method: Post, Status Code: *red* 403 Forbidden. Which is then followed by the 405 from generator/ (Method Not Allowed). < I hope this is what you meant, I have little experience here..